# Contextual filter doesn't work with the name of the entity reference, it only works with its ID

Tags: views, 8

why is the contextual filter below only working the the id of the entity reference ID? I would to search by name like by "Oceanography" or "Ecology and Evolution", but i'm not sure how. If i add a relationship the contextual filter doesn't even work with the ID number. Please help. Thanks in advace.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Drupal 7 this configuration should work for you :
[image]
But for some reason it doesn't work, so your alternative is [Views Taxonomy Term Name Depth](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_taxonomy_term_name_depth) module if you are working with **Drupal 8.6 or higher version**:``

1. Install and enable the module.
2. Add contextual filter **Content: Has taxonomy term name with Depth**
   [image]
3. Save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. My vocabulary doesn't show up as an option, because as you can see in the screenshot above the value/s of the "research area/s" field come from a content type reference method, so do you know what i should do?